# Creating a Notification Bar with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

This is the code I'm working with:

```
<div style="width:100%; position:absolute; border:0px; background-color:#232323; color:#ffffff; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; font-size:12px" align="center">
```

TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST

What it does is basically add a bar to the top of your website where you can enter text similar to what you see here: http://demo.fiverrscript.com/

What needs to be changed in my code to make this appear at the bottom of the screen instead of at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the **bottom:0px** to the style tag.

```
<div style="width:100%; position:absolute; bottom:0px border:0px; background-color:#232323; color:#ffffff; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; font-size:12px" align="center">
```

Also, the `width:100%` wont work so you should also add `left:0px` and `right:0px;`

Answer (score 0):

try to change position:absolute to **position:fixed** and add **bottom:0**